# Error: "app_name" is not translated in af

Tags: android, translation

I am new at Android coding and this forum. When I am trying to run the project to test it I am getting the following error:-

> "app_name" is not translated in af, am, ar, be, bg, ca, cs, da, de, el, en-rGB, en-rIN, es, es-rUS, et, et-rEE, fa, fi, fr, fr-rCA, hi, hr, hu, hy-rAM, in, it, iw, ja, ka-rGE, km-rKH, 
>    ko, lo-rLA, lt, lv, mn-rMN, ms, ms-rMY, nb, nl, pl, pt, pt-rBR, pt-rPT, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sv, sw, th, tl, tr, uk, vi, zh-rCN, zh-rHK, zh-rTW, zu

in `values/strings.xml`

**strings.xml:-**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
>
> <string name="app_name">ThessMuseams</string>
> <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
> <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
> ```

Comment: Do you have anything like `values-af/strings.xml`?

Comment: No. I have nothing like this.

Comment: It should be just a warning and your app should work fine. You can translate every string including the app name into all those languages but it makes usually no sense to do that for every language. Although I'm wondering why you see it.. take it as a friendly reminder that you could translate it :)

Comment: Thanks very much!! I hope it work becaouse is for a course I have. Tanks again for your help

Comment: For **Android Studio** refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45585534/6521116)

Comment: [Avoid Android Lint complains about not-translated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12590739/6521116)

Comment: But, signed apk is not getting generated due to this error.

Answer (score 82):

In your `ADT` go to `window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking`

Find there `MissingTranslation` and change its `Severity` to `Warning`.

Comment: I am doing this, but its not saving

Comment: what do you mean by not saving? change the things as per answer, then apply it and press ok. changes will be saved.

Comment: In mine it was Eclipse > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking, then set severity as warning, make sure to click `Apply`, then click `OK`.

Comment: Search for **MissingTranslation** not *Missing Translation*.

Answer (score 46):

With Android Studio, you can prevent lint from checking the MissingTranslation warning. Add the following to your app/build.gradle:

To ignore this in a gradle build add this to the android section of your build file:

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
       disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is more suitable than the other solutions

Answer (score 19):

For **Android Studio** you can use either of the below ways to solve this issue

**Method 1. Disable MissingTranslation check in build.gradle with**

```
android {
     lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}
```

**Method 2. Ignore the MissingTranslation in you resource strings file with**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" >

  <!-- your strings here; no need now for the translatable attribute -->

</resources>
```

**Method 3. Set translatable to false on specific string with**

```
<string name="hello" translatable="false">hello</string>
```

You also can refer to [Avoid Android Lint complains about not-translated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12590739/6521116)

Answer (score 8):

You should disable the :
"Run full error check when exporting app and abort if fatal errors are found".

you can disable it from option in :

"Window" > "Preferences" > "Android" > "Lint Error Checking"

You should be able to disable

"Run full error check when exporting app and abort if fatal errors are found".

Answer (score 8):

Try adding translatable="[true/false]".

```html
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">ThessMuseams</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is thrown by a check called lint which checks every dependency and guesses you want your app to be translated into all language the libraries you use are translated, in case of maps basically everyone. There is some setting for lint in the Eclipse preferences(Missing Translation). You could completely turn lint off or configure it so it ignores the translation warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Just click the Checkbox dropdown icon near AVD Manager . Then Select Clear Lint Warnings. 
That will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

How to disable Translations error messages

If you want to suppress the error message then go to,

On Mac OS X,

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking

Solving Eclipse Android Lint Translation error messages

On Windows,

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows,

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking
[Preferences Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJewB.png)

Run full error check must be unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You can write translation of the text to "Translations editor".

Answer (score -3):

I use android studio(v1.2), add the following build script then solved the issue:

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```